# Is there a way to use if-else statement for finding columns with the smallest value in df?

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement

Could you please help me with the following question?

This is a reproducible example of df in R that I have:

```
name <- c("cat", "dog", "fish", "chicken", "dino")
age <- c(29, 30, 100, 12, 1000)
start_pos <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
end_pos <- c(1, 2, 5, 7, 5)


df <- data.frame(name, age, start_pos, end_pos,
                                      stringsAsFactors = F)

df
```

I am trying to sort out this data so that I have in my df the columns only if their end_pos-start_pos equals 0. So, only a cat, dog and dino are supposed to stay in df.

I was thinking of doing it using if else statement, like

```
if(end_pos-start_pos=0){
  print("yes")
}
```

However, the errors started to appear.
Is it a good way to use if else statement for solving this task? Could you please recommend me another way of thinking about this task?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Minor remarks:
1) use ```==``` as a comparison and not ```=``` 
2) you don't need if(x == y){action} else{action} but you can use the ```ifelse``` function (for example ```df$equal <- ifelse(df$start_pos == df$end_pos, "yes", "no")```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest thing probably is to `subset` by a logical condition.

```
subset(df, start_pos - end_pos == 0)       
#   name  age start_pos end_pos
# 1  cat   29         1       1
# 2  dog   30         2       2
# 5 dino 1000         5       5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[start_pos == end_pos]
   name  age start_pos end_pos
1:  cat   29         1       1
2:  dog   30         2       2
3: dino 1000         5       5
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to `ifelse()` you could use `filter()` function of the `dplyr` package, like this

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% filter(start_pos == end_pos)
```

If you want to use base R, the alternative is `df[df$start_pos == df$end_pos, ]`.